# Что делает макрос LOWORD?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, define

Потихоньку погружаюсь в программирование на WinAPI, и некоторые макросы меня немного озадачивают. Среди них макрос `LOWORD(I)`.
Не могли бы Вы объяснить, что происходит в строке ниже?)

`#define LOWORD(l) ((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(l)) & 0xffff))`

Comment: ((DWORD_PTR)(l)) & 0xffff) это значение в пределах 16 бит (два байта), так как в  0xffff  записаны 16 единиц( 0xffff  == 2^16 - 1)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А для чего этот макрос используется в контексте обработки сообщений? Зачем использовать это преобразование?

Comment: или я выпил слышком много, или у вас есть ответ от zed вам дает явный ответ на этот вопрос...С Новым Годом!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы инициализируете макрос LOWORD, то есть, если в функции main у вас есть `LOWORD(L)`, то у вас будет выводится число, которое считается по этой "формуле": `((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(L)) & 0xffff))`.

Что делает эта формула?

1) Возвращает первые два младших байта числа L: `((DWORD_PTR)(l)) & 0xffff)`

2) Явно приводит это все к типу WORD: `((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(L)) & 0xffff))`

Вот ссылка на документацию: [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms632659(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 7):

Делает ровно то, о чём и говорит его название - возвращает 2 младших байта.

Например:

```
DWORD l = 0x11223344;
WORD w = LOWORD(l);   // w = 0x3344
```